# Data normalization for a recommender

Tags: data-transformation, dataset, normalization

this question is a copy from [DataScience forum](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/2501/data-scheduling-for-recommender). I do hope I will get much more information and help here.

At the moment I am doing some data experiments with the [Graphlab toolkit](http://graphlab.com/products/create/docs/). First of all, I have the following SFrame, with the three columns:

```
Users Items Rating
```

The pair in the same row from every `Users` and `Items` values build the unique key and the `Rating` is the corresponded float value. These values are not normalised. First of all, I performed the following normalisation:

1. Division of every rating value of specific user by the rating maximum from this user (scale between 0 and 1)
2. Take the logarithm of every rating value

Afterward I create a recommender model and evaluate the basic metrics for it.

In this topic I invite everybody to discuss another interesting normalisation methods. If anybody could tell some good method for data preparation, it would be great. The results could be evaluated regarded to the metrics and I can publish it here.

*Some additional information over data set:*

My dataset originates from some music site where the users rated some tracks. I have approximately 100 000 users and 300 000 tracks. Total number of ratings is over 3 million (actually the matrix is sparse). This is the most simple data set, which I am analyzing now. In the future I can (and will) use some additional information about the users and tracks (f.e. duration, year, genre, band etc). At the moment I'm just interested in collectibg some methods for rating normalisation without using additional information (users & items features). My problem is that the data set didn't have any `Rating` at first. I created the column `Rating` myself based on the number of events for unique `User-Item` pair (I have this information). You can of course understand that some users can hear some tracks many times, and another users only one time. Consequently the dispersion is very high and I want to reduce it (normalise the ratings value).

*Something else:*

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_%28statistics%29) has some useful methods for normalization. Any ideas, what could be good in this case?

Comment: Is `rating` a bounded value with limits given by the website?

Comment: Theoretical no. Once more - unnormalized rating is just number of events for one user-track pair. Every user can hear every track million times (in theory). Practical the value is of course bounded (I would like to use limited). Anyway I will here distinguish between constant and bounded, is surely not constant, the user can hear the same track in the future some times more.